# Regroup/rename XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I got an XML structure like this:

```
<OrderLineItems>
<SKU/>
<ItemName>ÁFONYÁS FÁNK</ItemName>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<Price>350</Price>
<LineTotal>350</LineTotal>
<Meta/>
</OrderLineItems>
<OrderLineItems>
<SKU/>
<ItemName>CSIRKE SALÁTA ÖNTETTEL</ItemName>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<Price>1150</Price>
<LineTotal>1150</LineTotal>
<Meta/>
</OrderLineItems>
```

I want that to output like this:

```
<basket>
<item> ->OrderLineItems
<billitem_code></billitem_code> -> SKU
<billitem_name></billitem_name>  -> this will be the ItemName
<billitem_amount></billitem_amount> ->Quantity
<billitem_unitprice></billitem_unitprice> ->Price
</item>
</basket>
```

I have managed to read the XML and output some of the basic lines

```
$xml -> customer -> name = $orderxml -> Order -> BillingFullName;
```

But i've failed to go through the ordered items if there are more than 1.

Any suggestions how to manage this?

Current CODE:

```
 <?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
header("Content-type:text/xml");

//Load
require "apiclass/database.php";
define("DEFAULT_XML_FILE",dirname(__FILE__).'/default.xml');

//Database 
$db = new Database;

//get XML
$order_id = $_GET["order_id"];
$order_file = "xml/order_id-".$order_id.".xml";

//XML 
$orderxml = simplexml_load_file($order_file);
$customerid = $orderxml -> Order -> CustomerId;

$xml = simplexml_load_file(DEFAULT_XML_FILE);

//Converting loaded XML to output format
$xml -> customer -> id = $orderxml -> Order -> CustomerId;
$xml -> orderdate = $orderxml -> Order -> OrderDate;
$xml -> customer -> name = $orderxml -> Order -> BillingFullName;
$xml -> customer -> tel = $orderxml -> Order -> BillingPhone;
$xml -> customer -> address -> postalcode = $orderxml -> Order -> BillingPostCode;
$xml -> customer -> address -> city = $orderxml -> Order -> BillingCity;
$xml -> customer -> address -> district = $orderxml -> Order -> BillingState;
$xml -> customer -> address -> street = $orderxml -> Order -> BillingAddress1;
$xml -> customer -> address -> number = $orderxml -> Order -> BillingAddress2;
$xml -> customer -> address -> description = $orderxml -> Order -> CustomerNote;
$xml -> payment_method = $orderxml -> Order -> ShippingMethod;

foreach($orderxml -> Order -> OrderLineItems -> ItemName as $key => $value)
{
$xml -> basket -> item -> billitem_name =  $value ;
}

$xml -> deliveryprice = $orderxml -> Order -> FeeTotal;
$xml -> totalprice = $orderxml -> Order -> OrderTotal;
print $xml -> asXML();

//Debuggolás
//echo '<pre>';
//var_dump($xml);
//echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Please show your actual code... We may help you enhancing it

Comment: I've updated with the current code. I'm completly missing the point how to go though teh <OrderLineItems>-s if there are more than 1.

Comment: Check `SimpleXMLElement::addChild()`. But I suggest reading about XSLT. It is a language specific to transform XML documents. PHP supports it via ext/xsl.

Comment: I'm not sure how thsi helps to go through all the <OrderLineItems> named childes (and all of its sub childs) then output them with different names.

Comment: i've also looked at XSLT, but if i'm correct, it doesn't convert one XML to another XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most fine way to transform your XML is probably [XSLT](http://php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php), a language for transforming XML documents into other XML documents. Also [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is more powerful than SimpleXML for import/transform nodes.

With SimpleXML, you can use `->addChild(name,value)->addChild(name,value)->...`.

Otherwise, you can use a *trick*. Divide your destination XML template in two parts:

```
$xmlDefault ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<basket/>';

$itemTemplate = '<item>
<billitem_code></billitem_code>
<billitem_name></billitem_name>
<billitem_amount></billitem_amount>
<billitem_unitprice></billitem_unitprice>
</item>
';
```

Load your source XML file:

```
$orderxml       = simplexml_load_file( $order_file );
```

Select `<OrderLineItems>` elements:

```
$orderLineItems = $orderxml->OrderLineItems;
```

And then create the new destination XML with same `<item>` number of `$orderLineItems`:

```
$newXml = "<basket>\n".str_repeat( $itemTemplate, count( $orderLineItems ) )."</basket>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $newXml );
```

Now you can add each node:

```
$key = 0;
foreach( $orderLineItems as $node )
{
    $xml->item[$key]->billitem_code      = $node->SKU;
    $xml->item[$key]->billitem_name      = $node->ItemName;
    $xml->item[$key]->billitem_amount    = $node->Quantity;
    $xml->item[$key]->billitem_unitprice = $node->Price;
    $key++;
}
```

`$xml` final contents:

```
<basket>
    <item>
        <billitem_code></billitem_code>
        <billitem_name>ÁFONYÁS FÁNK</billitem_name>
        <billitem_amount>1</billitem_amount>
        <billitem_unitprice>350</billitem_unitprice>
    </item>
    <item>
        <billitem_code></billitem_code>
        <billitem_name>CSIRKE SALÁTA ÖNTETTEL</billitem_name>
        <billitem_amount>1</billitem_amount>
        <billitem_unitprice>1150</billitem_unitprice>
    </item>
</basket>
```